# Operation not permitted /usr/bin macos catalina

Tags: root, macos-catalina

I was trying to move a file to /usr/bin but operation not permitted

So i tried sudo to copy to the destination folder/usr/bin

Again operation not permitted, so i went to system preferences and enabled root user .

Even enabling root user , the operation was permitted.

Need some help.

Comment: You could simply add the path to this file to the `PATH` environment variable so that you could run `your_file` in the shell and it would automatically find where it's located.

Comment: Recent versions of macOS, including Catalina have much stricter security hardening, including access to critical system areas. If you need to add files for coding/development, it probably would be better to put them in /Users/[Username], and as @ForceBru related, add the `PATH` environment to your loaded profile file.